# apply() with user defined function

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to write a cost function for a logistic regression and have only managed to do so using a for loop. I want to use the apply function, but have some problems with that.
Given the following data:

```
     ones    exam1    exam2 decision
[1,]    1 34.62366 78.02469        0
[2,]    1 30.28671 43.89500        0
[3,]    1 35.84741 72.90220        0
[4,]    1 60.18260 86.30855        1
[5,]    1 79.03274 75.34438        1
[6,]    1 45.08328 56.31637        0
```

The regression function is simply the sigmoid function of the linear combination of the parameters and the input values.

So this is the code I have written:

```
sigmoid <- function(y){
    return (1/(1 + exp(-y)))
}

hyp <- function(param, input){
    return (sigmoid(param %*% input))
}

cost <- function(param, temp){
    costcumul <- 0
    for(i in 1:length(temp[,1])){
        costcumul <- costcumul + temp[i,4]*log(hyp(param,temp[i,-4])) + (1-temp[i,4])*log(1 hyp(param,temp[i,-4]))
    }
    return ((-1)*costcumul/length(temp[,1]))
}
```

Before using the cost function I transform my data.frame into a matrix and use that matrix as an argument in the cost function.

I would like to use the apply() function inside the cost() function instead of looping through each row and after using apply I want to sum over each row using rowSums.

First I have rewritten the cost function so that it only calculates the cost of a single row:

```
testfunc <- function(p,x){
return (x[4]*log(hyp(p,x[-4])) + (1-x[4])*log(1-hyp(p,x[-4])))
}
```

then I tried to use apply in the following way:

```
apply(temp,1,testfunc,param = "param")
```

I get an error of the form: "Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument(s) (param = "param")"

I think my problem is specifying the parameters of the function. In my testfunc() function I have the parameter x, do I need to specify that parameter in the call of apply() or does the apply function know that a non-specified parameter is supposed to be a row of temp matrix in this case?

Comment: To start with, your `testfunc` function accepts `p` argument instead of `param`.

Comment: Ah yes, that was the problem. Thanks a lot, I didn't see that.